# JObject & CamelCase conversion with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I convert a generic JObject to camelCase plain json string?
I've tried with JsonSerializerSettings but doesn't work (Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.11)

```
[Test]
public void should_convert_to_camel_case()
{
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    });

    var jo = new JObject();
    jo["CamelCase"] = 1;

    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);
    serializer.Serialize(writer,jo);

    var serialized = stringWriter.ToString();

    Assert.AreEqual("{\"camelCase\":1}", serialized);
}
```

**UPDATE**
According to [http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/23853](https://web.archive.org/web/20171005181503/http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/23853) that cannot be done (tnx to @nick_w for the link)

Answer (score 52):

This question starts from a JObject and wants to work to a camel-cased JSON object.  If you are actually starting from an object and want to get to a JObject that is already camelcased, then you can do this:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer()
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
var jo = JObject.FromObject(someDataContract, serializer);
```

The resulting 'jo' will be camelcased.

Comment: How can I perform the opposite: `JObject.Load(jsonReader)` by specifying the resolver?

Comment: Tried this with `JObject` instance method `ToObject<T>(serializer)` but it does not work

Comment: JObject is not serialized, it is written "as is", so this answer isn't going to work.

Answer (score 25):

According to [this Json.NET issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20171005181503/http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/23853), when serializing a `JObject` this way the contract resolver is ignored:

> When serializing a JObject the contract resolvers seems to be ignored.  Surely this is not how it is supposed to be?
>   
> Closed Jan 30, 2013 at 8:50 AM by [JamesNK](https://web.archive.org/web/20171005181503/http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/JamesNK)
>   
> That does make sense but it is too big a breaking change I'm afraid.

Inspired by the workaround on that page, you could do something like this:

```
var jo = new JObject();
jo["CamelCase"] = 1;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jo);
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject, settings);

Assert.AreEqual("{\"camelCase\":1}", serialized);
```

**Edit:**

Good point about the `Dictionary<string, object>`. So doing it this way skips the additional `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, but it also mitigates the need for the `ExpandoObject`, which is important if you are using .NET 3.5.

```
Dictionary<string, object> jo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
jo.Add("CamelCase", 1);

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jo, settings);

Assert.AreEqual("{\"camelCase\":1}", serialized);
```

Comment: don't think serialize + deserialize + serialize is too efficient.

Comment: as a workaround I've switched from JObject do Dictionary<string, object>.

Comment: Thanks, I used `Dictionary<string,object>`

Answer (score 6):

As of [this](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/05/08/json-net-5-0-release-5-defaultsettings-and-extension-data) May 8th, 2013 blog post by James Newton-King regarding the 5.0 release of Json.NET, this has been addressed with the addition of "DefaultSettings".  The example from that page follows but read the page for details for 3rd party libraries.

```
// settings will automatically be used by JsonConvert.SerializeObject/DeserializeObject
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };

Employee e = new Employee
    {
    FirstName = "Eric",
    LastName = "Example",
    BirthDate = new DateTime(1980, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    Department = "IT",
    JobTitle = "Web Dude"
    };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e);
// {
//   "firstName": "Eric",
//   "lastName": "Example",
//   "birthDate": "1980-04-20T00:00:00Z",
//   "department": "IT",
//   "jobTitle": "Web Dude"
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static JsonSerializer FormattingData()
{
   var jsonSerializersettings = new JsonSerializer {
   ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
   return jsonSerializersettings;
}


public static JObject CamelCaseData(JObject jObject) 
{   
   var expandoConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
   dynamic camelCaseData = 
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jObject.ToString(), 
   expandoConverter); 
   return JObject.FromObject(camelCaseData, FormattingData());
```

}