# Deserialize JSON into C# Queue of Custom Object

Tags: c#, json

I feel like a dingdong not being able to figure this out, but hoping someone can either help me or point me in the right direction.

I'm currently converting individual files for a game i'm working on into a JSON Object. Currently, the structure of the song is as follows:

```
        public readonly int Id = 1;

        public readonly int BPM = 120;
        public readonly string Name = "Baby's";

        public readonly string Artist = "Brian";

        protected Song SongFile;

        public Queue<NoteChart> Chart = new Queue<NoteChart>();

        Chart.Enqueue(new NoteChart { gemType = 1, Key = "D", Lane = 8, beatTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 84) });
```

Pretty standard stuff I presume. Anyways, i'm having a iddue turning that Chart.Enqueue into a JSON object so I can parse it that way instead of having it typed out. So far I have:

```
  "Id": 1,
  "BPM": 120,
  "Name": "Baby",
  "Artist": "Brian",
  "SongFile": "Songs/Baby",
  "Chart": {
  }
```

But as you can see, i'm stuck on the Chart portion. How would I succesfully map it into JSON to be converted into C#? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Visual Studio can "paste JSON as classes", also look at System.Text.Json to deserialize it

Comment: Thanks aepot, I understand that part and I apologize if my question wasn't worded clearly; I was more wondering how to turn the Chart.Enque line in the top code into the JSON equivalent. Thank you though!

Comment: `string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Chart)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to

Comment: Is there anyway to skip the step of creating it in C# first and creating it all within JSON instead?

Comment: Sure, implement manually pattern "State Machine" with `Utf8JsonReader`/`*Writer`. Btw, i can't figure out how you can do it in C# without C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not find any problem

```
var chartItem = new ChartItem();

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(chartItem, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

public class ChartItem
{
    public readonly int Id = 1;

    public readonly int BPM = 120;
    public readonly string Name = "Baby's";

    public readonly string Artist = "Brian";

    protected string SongFile;

    public Queue<object> Chart =new ();
    
    public ChartItem ()
    {
        Chart.Enqueue(new  { gemType = 1, Key = "D", Lane = 8, beatTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 84) });
    }
    
}
```

json

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "BPM": 120,
  "Name": "Baby's",
  "Artist": "Brian",
  "Chart": [
    {
      "gemType": 1,
      "Key": "D",
      "Lane": 8,
      "beatTime": "00:00:05.0840000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Let rest in peace allmighty JSON.NET

Comment: @aepot Let rest in peace allmighty Text.Json. Glory to  an admirable Newtonsoft.Json! The best json library ever!

Comment: No more nugets! :)

Comment: @aepot Glory to nugets. The most facinated net util

Comment: Well, they are two children of the same father, so long live to James Newton King!

Comment: @AlbertoChiesa Yes, you are right. Long live to James Newton King! And by the way , his answer to Newtonsoft.Json question was down voted  15 times at this resource. And he was told he was wrong and  didn't know how Newtonsoft.Json works. You can search and find his answer here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40274581/1395758 as a memento.